# ServletContext and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

How can I get the ServletContext inside an Interceptor in Spring MVC 3?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Since interceptor is a bean, you can simply autowire it:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Comment: this is gold. what a time-saver! Cheers, mate!

Comment: And don't forget to assign getters and setters or spring won't be able to autowire

Comment: What are the configuration to be done around it? Just doing the autowire above does not work for me

Answer (score 6):

Please look at this example

http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-interceptor.html

and then request.getSession().getServletContext()

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Don't use it. You shouldn't create a session if it isn't needed.