# Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc

I'm trying to upload pdf files in the server. And i;m using the following block of code into the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = /submit, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String upload(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

   //some code here

   String name = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/pdf/" + filename);
   File dest = new File(name);
   try {
        file.transferTo(dest);
   }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
   }

   return "redirect:/details";
```

I'm doing this in order to store the pdf's into the pdf file. In my localhost works fine but when i'm executing this on the server i'm taking the following exception:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;
frontend.controller.EsteemRatingsController.handleFormUpload(EsteemRatingsController.java:113)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

If i remove the lines that provide above in the controller class is working(ofcource without uploading the pdf's). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What web container are you using? Looks like you're running on something old.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That method `request.getServletContext()` was introduced in servlet 3.0.  Make sure your container/library support that version.

edit:   tomcat 6 only have servlet 2.5, see http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

it can be autowired: [ServletContext and Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739491/servletcontext-and-spring-mvc)

```
public class Xxxx{
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

       //some code here

       String name = context.getRealPath("/pdf/" + filename);
...
```

Comment: So instead of this method which method can i use that apache 6.0.24 can support it?

Comment: Can spring inject `ServletContext` for you? Haven't tried, but i guess it can.

Comment: Thank you a lot for you replies and your time. I saw on the internet that it can but i'm very new in all this and i can't understand.Can you help me?

Comment: just add ServletContext to your method signature:  `public String upload(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, ServletContext ctx) {` and spring should do the magic for you.

Comment: Thank you again but there is a problem.The ServletContext is an inerface and so i have an error which says "Could not instantiate bean class [javax.servlet.ServletContext]: Specified class is an interface"