# How to get the project name or path of from context or other class?

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, path

my project run on:

```
hXXp://localhost:8080/mvc
```

but when I rebuild on client part it would be:

```
hxxp://localhsot:8080/mvc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I want get the parameter of `mvc` or `mvc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` in one of my controller of SpringMVC.

（because I will setting some dynamic picture path）

How to get these names in context or controller class?

Comment: You can also use autowire serlvet context directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739491/servletcontext-and-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29):

```
@RequestMapping
public String handle(HttpServletRequest req) {
    final String context = req.getContextPath();  //mvc or mvc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    //...
}
```