# getServletConfig().getServletContext() equivalent in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I referred to a lot of posts but still I am unable to find a correct working answer.
I want to get it from my Java class itself and not using EL in jsp.

How to get the servlet context path in Spring?

Comment: You mean in a Spring MVC controller? In the view?

Comment: In the spring MVC controller. Not the view.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

for SpringMVC

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is implementing [ServletConfigAware](http://srcrr.com/java/spring/3.1.0/reference/org/springframework/web/context/ServletConfigAware.html) in the class that depends on `ServletContext`. In the `setServletConfig` method you'll get an instance of `ServletContext` and you can do there what you have to do.

```
public class MyClass implements ServletConfigAware {

    private ServletConfig config;

    public void setServletConfig(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        this.config = servletConfig;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, does this setServletConfig method be called just one time, at initialization? It would solve my problem as I need for a way to set a property at initialization time.

Comment: @Phate, as far as I know it is called once after instance creation. More details on that here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletConfigAware.html

Answer (score 4):

A solution is posted here: [ServletContext and Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739491/servletcontext-and-spring-mvc)

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```