# Spring MVC how to access Static Resource from Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Okay I'm working with Spring MVC 4.0 and I'm having a problem reading a `txt` file from a Controller.

I set in my dispatcher-servlet

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/docs/**" location="/docs/"/>
```

so at docs I set a `file.txt`, I want to read that file from a controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFile() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("docs/file.txt")); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {

        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return  sb.toString();
    }

}
```

I have tried all the paths for FileReader(path) and I can't get that file... how can I do it?

My directory structure is:

```
Application
---WepPages
-------META-INF
-------WEB-INF
-------docs

---SourcePackages
---Libraries
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You're mixing definitions of "resource". Static resources are handled automatically by Spring MVC and don't need dedicated controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this to aggregate a list of js and css files for my view.
The file paths can be passed to the view so they don't need to be registered manually.
This is how I am doing it -

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

WebApplicationContext webappContext;

List<String> jsFiles = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> cssFiles = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
public HomeController(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException{

    webappContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);


    Resource[] jsResources = webappContext.getResources("content/modules/**/*.js");
    Resource[] cssResources = webappContext.getResources("content/modules/**/*.css");

    for (Resource resource : jsResources) {
        jsFiles.add(resource.getURL().getPath());
    }
    for (Resource resource : cssResources) {
        cssFiles.add(resource.getURL().getPath());
    }
}
@RequestMapping({ "/", "/home**" })
public ModelAndView getHomePage() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    modelAndView.setViewName("home");
    modelAndView.addObject("jsFiles", jsFiles);
    modelAndView.addObject("cssFiles", cssFiles);

    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The resources are typically packed to war. That's why you can't find them in file system. Though you can still access them using classloader:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/docs/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring can access underlying resources by using [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) interface:

```
@Value("file:/docs/file.txt")
private Resource myFile;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFile() throws IOException {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile.getFile()));
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using the `ServletContext`. e.g.

```
ServletContext context = //...
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/docs/file.txt");
```

Also, check this - [ServletContext and Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739491/738746).